# Where is getStyleUrl() MapBox 5.0.2

Tags: android, mapbox

Where is `getStyleUrl()` in `MapView`? There is no such method anymore. Where do I get the style url now on MapBox v5.0.2?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `mapboxMap.getStyleUrl()` on v5.0.+.

Comment: Instead of saying "now", it would be more useful to provide a link to a change log (or better yet, commit - if it's an open-source library) indicating the version where this change was introduced, so that future readers will know if this answer applies in their case.

Answer (score 0):

**This reference to the documentation of the method.
There and other methods of this class**
https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/api/5.0.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/MapboxMap.html#getStyleUrl--